# Display JSON data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I a little new to JS and was struggling to display JSON data in a tabular format. The JSON is below

```js
var js = {
  "columns": [{
      "title": "t1"
    },
    {
      "title": "t2"
    },
    {
      "title": "t3"
    },
    {
      "title": "t4"
    },
    {
      "title": "t5"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "t1row1",
      "t2row1",
      "t3row1",
      "t4row1",
      "t5row1"
    ],
    [
      "t1row2",
      "t2row2",
      "t3row2",
      "t4row2",
      "t5row2"
    ],
    [
      "t1row3",
      "t2row3",
      "t3row3",
      "t4row3",
      "t5row3"
    ]
  ]
};

let text = "<table border='1'>"
text += "<tr>";
for (let x in js.columns) {


  text += "<th>" + js.columns[x].title + "</th>";

}
text += "</tr>";
text += "<tr>";
for (let y in js.columns) {

  for (var v in js.rows) {

    text += "<td>" + js.rows[v] + "</td>";

  }
}

text += "</tr>";
text += "</table>"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I have used these loops to get the data in tabular format but I am unable to send the "rows" data into 3 separate rows under the titles. By the current code I am able to put the 5 column name correctly but we have a single row with [t1row1,t2row1,t3row1,t4row1,t5row1] ,  [t1row2,t2row2,t3row2,t4row2,t5row2]  ...etc with data inserted instead of 3 rows. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am not aware of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your result, you need to iterate over the rows of data and add them to the table while preserving the structure. You have the open/close `TR` *outside* of your loop. That means you're making one large `TR` with a lot of `TD` in it (as your result shows you).

You need to move them *into* your loop, the loop that itterates through the rows. Update code:

```js
var js = {
  "columns": [
    {
      "title": "t1"
    },
    {
      "title": "t2"
    },
    {
      "title": "t3"
    },
    {
      "title": "t4"
    },
    {
      "title": "t5"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "t1row1",
      "t2row1",
      "t3row1",
      "t4row1",
      "t5row1"
    ],
    [
      "t1row2",
      "t2row2",
      "t3row2",
      "t4row2",
      "t5row2"
    ],
    [
      "t1row3",
      "t2row3",
      "t3row3",
      "t4row3",
      "t5row3"
    ]
  ]
};

let text = "<table border='1'>";

text += "<tr>";
for (let x in js.columns) {
  text += "<th>" + js.columns[x].title + "</th>";
}
text += "</tr>";

for (let i in js.rows) {
  text += "<tr>";
  for (let j in js.rows[i]) {
    text += "<td>" + js.rows[i][j] + "</td>";
  }
  text += "</tr>";
}

text += "</table>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Added a little more context about the solution :)

Comment: @Martijn IMHO this answer is unworthy of a good coder

Comment: @MisterJojo Hm, its not pretty indeed. But it is the code of OP, with a fix applied to it. Can it be cleaner? Yes. But does it solve the problem? Also yes.

Comment: @Martijn  what the OP is asking is how to display JS data in a table.
and he's looking for a way to code that. His algorithmic error is not part of his question. Proposing a more "clean" answer is precisely what I did, and I don't see how this deserves a serial downvote on several of my posts

Answer (score 1):

table element have specific method you should use : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

```js
const js = 
  { columns: 
    [ { title: 't1' } 
    , { title: 't2' } 
    , { title: 't3' } 
    , { title: 't4' } 
    , { title: 't5' } 
    ] 
  , rows: 
    [ [ 't1row1', 't2row1', 't3row1', 't4row1', 't5row1' ] 
    , [ 't1row2', 't2row2', 't3row2', 't4row2', 't5row2' ] 
    , [ 't1row3', 't2row3', 't3row3', 't4row3', 't5row3' ] 
  ] };

const table = document.querySelector('#demo').appendChild(document.createElement('table'));

let
  tHead = table.createTHead() 
, tBody = table.createTBody() 
, rowX  = tHead.insertRow()
  ;
js.columns.forEach(({title}) => rowX.insertCell().textContent = title);
js.rows.forEach(arr =>
  {
  rowX  = tBody.insertRow();
  arr.forEach( txt => rowX.insertCell().textContent = txt );
  });
```

```css
html {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 16px;
  }
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : darkblue;
  margin           : 1em;
  color            : black;
  }
table td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .2em .6em;
  min-width        : 4.2em;
  text-align       : center;
  }
table thead td {
  padding          : .3em .6em;
  background-color : #3acec2;
  font-weight      : bold;
 }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```